# ASP.NET Core Identity email confirmation URL for React routes

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using React router for my SPA and ASP.Net Core as an API backend using Identity for authentication. At the moment I'm trying to add email confirmation as part of the user registration process. What's troubling me is how to generate the confirmation URL without hard-coding the URL path into the backend.

This is what I'm currently working with:

```
// Somewhere in my UserService.cs...
// '_urlHelper' is an `IUrlHelper` injected into my service
var routeUrl = _urlHelper.RouteUrl("ConfirmEmail_Route",
    new EmailConfirmationRequest { Email = email, Token = token },
    requestScheme);
// Send the URL in some nicely formatted email
await _emailSender.SendConfirmationEmail(email, routeUrl);


// My API controller action to handle email confirmation
[HttpPost(Name = "ConfirmEmail_Route")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail([FromBody] EmailConfirmationRequest payload)
{
    var response = await _userService.ConfirmEmail(payload.Token, payload.Email);
    ...
}
```

The trouble is, that this generates a URL with a path like "/api/auth/ConfirmEmail?Email=..." but my React route is configured to handle a path like "/ConfirmEmail?Email=...". This means, when opening the URL the browser is obviously reaching the API controller action directly rather than going through my SPA (ignoring the fact the action expects a POST request).

All this makes good sense because `_urlHelper.RouteUrl(...)` only sees the controller actions within ASP.Net Core itself and knows nothing about the routes React uses. What I could do is hard-coding it somewhat like this:

```
var routeUrl = $"{requestScheme}://{hostname}/ConfirmEmail?Email={email}&Token={token}";
```

... which is not very versatile (I need to consider how to handle port number, subdomains etc.).

Are there any good alternatives I haven't been able to find yet?

---

**Edit 26/12/2020:**

It seems there's a little confusion about what the roles of my SPA and API backend are. To elaborate, this is my setup in Startup.cs (using .Net Core 2.1):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Other irrelevant setup left out for brevity
    // ...

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Setup routing
    // Specific routes are defined in controllers
    app.UseMvc();

    app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
    {
        builder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/api/error/{0}");
    });

    app.MapWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
    {
        builder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

        builder.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // For any path not beginning with "/api" return the SPA (Javascript) bundle
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    });
}
```

In other words: the REST API is supposed to be seen as an individual entity not caring about rendering a view but only exposing the functionality communicating in JSON. The React SPA is a bundled Javascript file that takes care of all the UI rendering and communicating with the REST API for signup, login and whatnot. All is secured using JWT (tokens) for authentication.

This means that the REST API does not care about the paths/URLs that the SPA uses to navigate the user through the application (at least as far as possible I'd like the API to be agnostic about how a client/SPA handles the URLs/UI/navigation - but in this case I might make an exception if necessary). So, there's no controller actions in the backend matching the routes used in the React routes SPA, which makes it difficult to `_urlHelper.RouteUrl(...)` but I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Create a page for Confirm page in front-end and when user click the link in email redirect the user to the front-end page with the token ad query string. When page load, check the query string and do a HTTP post to your API

Comment: @MichaelMao Do you mean a controller action "confirm page"? In that case, I feel like it defeats the purpose of an SPA. If not, then how do I generate the link to put in the email, so it doesn't point to my API endpoint?

Comment: Is you SPA hosting the login and other sign-up related pages?

Comment: Just generate the URL like your other SPA page?

Comment: @CeemahFour Depends what you mean by "hosting". Yes, everything UI related is handled by the SPA. The backend is supposed to be pure a JSON API. So JWT authentication tokens are generated by the API, but the SPA is rendering the UI for the user to enter credentials and fetching the token based on that.

Comment: @MichaelMao I've added some more context to my question. My API backend doesn't really know about the routes the SPA uses, so I'm not really "generating" any URLs for my "other SPA pages". However, since only the backend is able to send the email, the backend has to know where to link the user to. So I'm looking for a way to somehow bridge the SPA with the API without making the API too dependent on the SPA. I know it's a little tricky but I'm thinking there must be similar setups out there.

Comment: I’m guessing you’ve already checked this out https://link.medium.com/rnuKtpAPzcb and this https://github.com/karpikpl/identity-as-a-service

Comment: @CeemahFour No I haven't, but thanks :) However, I'm not using IdentityServer so I'm a little unsure what to take from those articles. They only seem to deal with login and not registration/confirmation. Perhaps you can elaborate if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

According you comment, **"My API backend doesn't really know about the routes the SPA uses"**.
What I think is you can ask frontend to pass the URL what they want when click the link in email.

1. User register will make a POST request to backend with

```
{
    account: xxx
    confirmEmailUrl: "https://www.example/confirmEmail" 
    // Front-end pass what URL they want and create the corresponding page on their side
    // So they need to create the page by themselves
}
```

2. Send email

```
var url = "https://www.example/confirmEmail" + userId
SendEmail(url)
```

So when user get email and click the link in email, it will redirect to the corresponding page created by frontend and you don't need to know any about frontend

3.Call the confirm API in frontend.

```
They need to implement this by themselves. 
In the confirm page they created when page loaded.
Get userId from query string and call the API you provide
```

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. I'll probably go with something like this if I don't find other options. I was hoping for something that could handle it through configuration or similar rather than client input, but I guess I'm probably asking for the impossible when the SPA and API are mostly separate.

Comment: Something you can try, provide a confirm for client so you have a fix URL now. You can get referral URL so you don't need the client to input the URL and ask them create a confirm page under a fix path like ```http://{client domain}/confirmEmail```